# In my iOS app the username and text fields won't get populated with the stored values in the view

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

In my app I retrieve the stored login credentials using keychain, and then set the `username` and `password` text fields with the retrieved values. But when the view loads, the text fields are empty.

```
-(void) awakeFromNib {
    [self retrieveStoredLoginInformation];
}

- (void) retrieveStoredLoginInformation {
    KeychainItemWrapper* keychain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"KeychainTest" accessGroup:nil];

    NSString *storedUsername = [keychain objectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount];

    NSString *storedPassword = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[keychain objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    **[self.username setText:storedUsername];

    [self.password setText:storedPassword];**
}
```

I have verified that the `awakeFromNib` method is called first. It retrieves the username and password correctly. Should the code to set the value in the text fields be present somewhere else?

What am I missing?

Edit 1: I have checked if the username and password are actually retrieved by printing them using NSLog
Also, it's a normal ViewController not a tableViewController.
I also tried setting it by using
self.username.text = storedUsername;
self.password.text = storedPassword;
That didn't work either.

This is how I have defined my fields and my viewDidLoad function.

```
@interface LoginViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *username;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *password;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    [[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] drawInRect:self.view.bounds];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];
}
```

Comment: self.password is your textfield

Comment: Is `self.password` `nil`?

Comment: R u using TableView..? Else set value as self.password.text=storedPassword..

Answer (score -1):

First, try to call `[super awakeFromNib]` before your retrieving code.
If this doesn't work and this code is in a view controller, try move your code to `-viewDidLoad`

Answer (score -1):

@Nandita Rao,

I thinks you should first check whether the "storedUsername" and "storedPassword" are available or not using simple NSLog before assigning it to textfields.

I hope it might help you.

Comment: How would printing the `storedUsername` and `storePassword` to the console help in anyway? -1

Comment: This in no way answers the users question then. It's a comment to gather more information so please leave a comment not an answer.